# Sorry, unrecognized username or password error after successful login

Tags: 7, users, forms

In user_login block form alter I'm attaching a validator : **ws_res_auth_authenticate** ( the last one in the dsm output below) and logging in a user  using this code:

```
 user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
```

Now this function is correctly logging in the user, opening a session since on refreshing the page it shows me logged in.

But the problem is that it is showing error "Sorry, unrecognized username or password.". In reality it appears to have logged in since on refresh it shows logged-in area and other My Account stuff. So it isn't redirecting. Just redirect it I'm calling PHP header function, then a "die".

In other words after pressing submit with login/passwd it shows error : "Sorry, unrecognized username or password." but if I refresh this page it shows logged-in area.

I've tried changing the order of validators in the form_alter so that my validator 'res_auth_authenticate' is called first. But still the same problem.

What am I missing?

#### What I'm trying to do

I've three types of accounts: Local account, on LDAP and CSV source. What I want is that if the logged in user is found in the CSV source, I want to log the user in.

### dsm($form['#validate']) output

```
... (Array, 7 elements)
0 (String, 32 characters ) ldap_user_grab_password_validate | (Callback) ldap_user_grab_password_validate();
1 (String, 24 characters ) user_login_name_validate | (Callback) user_login_name_validate();
2 (String, 66 characters ) ldap_authentication_core_override_user_login_au... | (Callback) ldap_authentication_core_override_user_login_au...();
3 (String, 52 characters ) ldap_authentication_user_login_authenticate_val... | (Callback) ldap_authentication_user_login_authenticate_val...();
4 (String, 38 characters ) noreqnewpass_user_login_final_validate | (Callback) noreqnewpass_user_login_final_validate();
5 (String, 32 characters ) readonlymode_check_form_validate | (Callback) readonlymode_check_form_validate();
6 (String, 22 characters ) ws_rest_auth_authenticate | (Callback) rest_auth_authenticate();
```

### Here is the full code

```
    <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Allow users to login using an external web service.
 *
 * Users can login to the site using a RESTful web service. If the user is
 * associated with a Drupal user, that user is logged in. If not, a new user is
 * created.
 */
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function ws_rest_auth_menu()
{
    $items['admin/config/people/rest_auth'] = array(
        'title' => 'REST Auth',
        'description' => 'Administer REST Auth settings.',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('ws_rest_auth_settings_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    );
    return $items;
}

/**
 * Form to administer REST Auth settings.
 */
function ws_rest_auth_settings_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();
    $form['rest_auth_general'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('General settings'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['rest_auth_general']['rest_auth_url'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Host'),
        '#description' => t('Enter the fully-formed URL of the authentication service.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_url'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['rest_auth_general']['rest_auth_param_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Username parameter'),
        '#description' => t('Enter the username parameter name that will get passed to the web service. If the username is buried inside the JSON response object, enter the hierarchy using <strong>\\</strong> as level delimiter. For example, if the username is inside <code>{"User": {"name": "Druplicon"}}</code>, enter <code>User\\name</code> in this box.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_param_name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['rest_auth_general']['rest_auth_param_pass'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Password parameter'),
        '#description' => t('Enter the password parameter name that will get passed to the web service. If the password is buried inside the JSON response object, enter the hierarchy using <strong>\\</strong> as level delimiter. For example, if the password is inside <code>{"User": {"password": "letmein"}}</code>, enter <code>User\\password</code> in this box.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_param_pass'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['rest_auth_advanced'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['rest_auth_advanced']['rest_auth_auth_side'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Authentication side'),
        '#description' => t('This options allows you to determine where authentication happens.<br /><em>Note: It is more secure to authenticate provider-side, but it may require additional code from the web service provider.</em>'),
        '#options' => array(
            'provider' => t('Provider (Web service)'),
            'consumer' => t('Consumer (Drupal)'),
        ),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_auth_side', 'provider'),
    );
    $form['rest_auth_advanced']['rest_auth_response_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Response username'),
        '#description' => t('If your authentication is consumer-side, and the username is located in a different part of the JSON response object, enter that location here. If the username is burried inside the JSON response object, enter the hierarchy using <strong>\\</strong> as level delimiter. For example, if the username is inside <code>{"User": {"username": "Druplicon"}}</code>, enter <code>User\\username</code> in this box.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_response_name'),
    );
    $form['rest_auth_advanced']['rest_auth_param_email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Email parameter'),
        '#description' => t('If the response contains an email address, enter the email parameter name that will be returned from the web service. If this is left empty or if the parameter is not found, the module will try to use the username as the account email. If the email is buried inside the JSON response object, enter the hierarchy using <strong>\\</strong> as level delimiter. For example, if the email is inside <code>{"User": {"email": "mail@example.com"}}</code>, enter <code>User\\email</code> in this box.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_param_email'),
    );
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    unset($roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID]);
    $form['rest_auth_advanced']['rest_auth_roles'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Roles'),
        '#description' => t('Select the role(s) you would like to assign to new users created by REST Auth.'),
        '#options' => $roles,
        '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_roles', array()),
    );
    if (module_exists('devel'))
        {
        $form['rest_auth_advanced']['rest_auth_debug'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => t('Debug'),
            '#description' => t('This option allows you to view the response object. Turn off for production websites.'),
            '#options' => array(
                0 => t('Disabled'),
                1 => t('Enabled'),
            ),
            '#default_value' => variable_get('rest_auth_debug', 0),
        );
        }
    return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function ws_rest_auth_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'user_login' || $form_id == 'user_login_block')
        {
        if (isset($form_state['input']['name']))
            {
            array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'ws_rest_auth_authenticate');

            dsm($form['#validate']);
            }
        }
}

/**
 * Authenticates the user.
 */
function ws_rest_auth_authenticate($form, &$form_state)
{
    $url = variable_get('rest_auth_url');
    $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $pass = $form_state['values']['pass'];
    $data = array(
        variable_get('rest_auth_param_name', 'name') => $name,
        variable_get('rest_auth_param_pass', 'pass') => md5($pass),
    );
    $options = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'data' => drupal_http_build_query($data),
    );
    $response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
    if (module_exists('devel') && variable_get('rest_auth_debug', 0))
        {
        dpm($response, t('Response'));
        }
    // Verify for response error
    if (isset($response->error))
        {
        drupal_set_message($response->error, 'error');
        }
    else
        {
        // Parse response data
        $data = json_decode($response->data, TRUE);
        if (module_exists('devel') && variable_get('rest_auth_debug', 0))
            {
            dpm($data, t('Data'));
            }
        if ($error = json_last_error())
            {
            // Error
            switch ($error)
                {
                case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                    drupal_set_message(t('The maximum stack depth has been exceeded'), 'error');
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                    drupal_set_message(t('Underflow or mode mismatch'), 'error');
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                    drupal_set_message(t('Unexpected control character found'), 'error');
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                    drupal_set_message(t('Syntax error. Invalid or malformed JSON'), 'error');
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                    drupal_set_message(t('Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'), 'error');
                    break;
                default:
                    drupal_set_message(t('Unknown error parsing data'), 'error');
                    break;
                }
            }
        else
            {
            // Success
            if ($uid = _rest_auth_login_register($data, $name, $pass, $form_state))
                {
                $form_state['uid'] = $uid;
                return true;
                dd(__LINE__);
                }
            }
        }
}

/**
 * Log in the user, registering if the user doesn't exist yet.
 */
function _rest_auth_login_register($data, $name, $pass, &$form_state)
{
    $account = null;

    //this user should not be existing in ldap_user

    $count = db_query("SELECT module FROM {authmap} WHERE authname = :authname and module <> :module ", array(':authname' => $name, ':module' => 'ws_rest_auth'))->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0)
        {
        //ignore it  as this user has already entry thru another extrnal authentication
        return FALSE;
        }

    // Authenticate if necessary
    // Create account if it does not exist
    if (!$account)
        {

        // Determine what the email for the user should be
        $mail_candidate = _rest_auth_parse_data($data, variable_get('rest_auth_param_email'));
        if (valid_email_address($mail_candidate))
            {

            // Use if it is a valid email
            $mail = $mail_candidate;
            }
        elseif (valid_email_address($name))
            {
            // Default to username as email
            $mail = $name;
            }
        else
            {
            drupal_set_message(t('A valid email was not found for this user'), 'error');
            return FALSE;
            }

        //A valid email has been found


        if (_rest_auth_user_exists($name))
            {
            //just verify the password and log him in
            $account = user_external_load($name);  //he must be existing in this
            }
        else
            {
            // Create and save new user
            $userinfo = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'pass' => $pass,
                'mail' => $mail,
                'init' => $mail,
                'status' => 1,
                'roles' => variable_get('rest_auth_roles', array()),
                'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
                'data' => $data,
            );
            // Provide hook to alter user information
            drupal_alter('rest_auth_user', $userinfo, $data);
            $account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $userinfo);
            // Set an error if the account creation failed

            if (!$account)
                {

                drupal_set_message(t('Error saving user account.'), 'error');
                return FALSE;
                }

            user_set_authmaps($account, array('authname_rest_auth' => $name));
            }
        }
    else
        {

        // Update $user->data with information from the server
        $userinfo = array('data' => $data);
        // Provide hook to alter user information
        $context = array('user' => clone $account);
        drupal_alter('rest_auth_user', $userinfo, $data, $context);
        user_save($account, $userinfo);

        }
    // Log the user in
    dd($account->uid, 'uid');
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;

    user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

    header('Location: http://localhost/my/user/1');
    die();
    return $account->uid;
}

/**
 * Checks if a username already exists.
 */
function _rest_auth_user_exists($name)
{
    if (db_query_range('SELECT 1 FROM {users} WHERE name = :name', 0, 1, array(':name' => $name))->fetchField())
        {
        return TRUE;
        }
    else
        {
        return FALSE;
        }
}

/**
 * Get the email based on the configured response path.
 */
function _rest_auth_parse_data($data, $xpath)
{
    if ($xpath)
        {
        $xpath = explode('\\', $xpath);
        $value = $data;
        foreach ($xpath as $key)
            {
            if (isset($value[$key]))
                {
                $value = $value[$key];
                }
            }
        return $value;
        }
}
```

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72312/drupal-7-login-with-external-database shows a method for authenticating against an external source

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't submit the form manually during the validation. The submit function will be automatically called if the validation passes. That means you should check for errors and use [`form_set_error`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) if your check fails.

The error message you are getting is because you try to send the login form manually with empty information. And the reason for the user is still logged in, despite of the error, is that the original form submit method will also be called since there are no validation errors.

Comment: I've added the module code. I've adapted it from https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_auth as it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is it or not, but I was poking around in the user.module and I came across the function user_login_final_validate (line 2184 from user.module).

The comments for that function state:

```
   /**
     * The final validation handler on the login form.
     *
     * Sets a form error if user has not been authenticated, or if too many
     * logins have been attempted. This validation function should always
     * be the last one.
     */
```

I noticed that final validate isn't in your list of validations, wondering if that could be causing it.

Comment: Looks like this is the one which is generating the error, even though user_login_submit has been called to log in and create a session for a user.